# How to use React.useContext in a function that does not render any components?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I need to get the current value of a context inside a function that is called on a specific event rather than inside a renderer.

### Example:

**logCurrentTheme.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {ThemeContext} from "./ThemeContext";
// ThemeContext is a context created by React.createContext()

function logCurrentTheme() {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  console.log(context.themeColor)
}
export {logCurrentTheme};
```

**in some other component I have**

```
//...
import {logCurrentTheme} from "./logCurrentTheme.js";
//...
const someComponent () => {
  return(
    <Button onClick={logCurrentTheme} title="Log Current Theme"/>
  );
}
```

The example above compiles successfully but once the button is clicked it throws the error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

I get that this is a "function" and not a "function component". But how else can I do this?

**Edit:**

[Working example based on @tudor's answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-dawn-x0nd6?file=/src/LogContextButton.js)

**LogContextButton.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useContextHelper } from "./ContextHelper";

export const LogContextButton = props => {
  var { logCurrentContextValue } = useContextHelper();
  return <button onClick={logCurrentContextValue}>{props.children}</button>;
};
```

**ContextHelper.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "./Context";

export const useContextHelper = () => {
  const currentValue = useContext(Context);
  const logCurrentContextValue = () => console.log(currentValue);
  return { logCurrentContextValue };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a hook which returns you that `logCurrentTheme` function:

```
export const useThemeHelper() {
  const {themeColor} = useContext(ThemeContext);
  
  const logCurrentTheme = () => console.log(themeColor);
  return {logCurrentTheme};
}

...

// and in your component: 
const SomeComponent () => {
  const {logCurrentTheme} = useThemeHelper();
  return(
    <Button onClick={logCurrentTheme} title="Log Current Theme"/>
  );
}
```

You cannot use a hook outside another hook or a component.

Comment: It didn't work. I think it's because a hook isn't a hook if it's not returning JSX to a rendered view. It can't return a function

Comment: a hook doesn't need to return JSX at all. How did you use it? can you create a codesandbox where it doesn't work?

Comment: Strangely, codesandbox didn't show the same error but it's still not working as React.useContext is returning **undefined** 

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-dawn-x0nd6?file=/src/LogContext.js)

Comment: you need to use the hook in a component *wrapped* by the context . The codesandbox link uses the hook outside of the context (in the component where the context is used) - you need to move it in one of the children of this component or move the context as a parent.